# How to show data frame data into table in R using shiny

Tags: r, shiny

My data look like as follow in data frame:

```
X
a        date     b     c    d     e     f     g     h     i 
1    7 Jan 17    80    80   -4    26    58    16    12    12
```

I want to show this data in table view in shiny.

In `ui.r` I have done as follow:

```
tableOutput("futureData")
```

and in `server.R` I want to show that data frame data in table

```
output$futureData <- renderTable()
```

What should I do?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I have replaced the html formatting by markdown which is used on SO.

Comment: A related question has been asked the day before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43590702/i-have-read-csv-file-and-want-to-show-table-format-in-r-using-shiny

Answer (score 3):

Please, try

```
output$futureData <- renderTable(
  {
    X <- data.frame(a = 1L, date = "7 Jan 17", b = 80L, c = 80L, d = -4L,
                    e = 26L, f = 58L, g = 16L, h = 12L, i = 12L)
    return(X)
  }
)
```

Note that `return(X)` can be replaced by a single `X`.